# C# WEB API POST : Method not found (404) or method not allowed (405)

Tags: asp.net

My prblem is that i'm trying to post a base64 image through the server via web api, and wehen i try to recall the method it returns error like "method not allowed" or "method not found", maybe i'm doing something wrong with these pieces of code, can you help me?
the controller name is "MemeController"

[i've also tryied with this post, but it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4ufl.png)
[HERE IS MY CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL838.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that the web server is allowing the MIME type of the file?

And try to send it with a tool like postman so you can find if the problem is in the front or in the backend

Comment: how do i made sure it?

Comment: it depend on the kind of web server. I think in iis ist under Extension filtering but i don't know for sure  Have you tried posting the file with postman or something like it ?

Comment: not yet, in case, how do i allow the mime type of the file?